# breakpoints in single-lined js-scripts with firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

i want to analyze an external js-file. but the file is single-lined and obfuscated. so i cannot set meaningful breakpoints. (though automatical unobfuscation, code-indentation is assumed to be possible).

first of all, what would your suggestion be to overcome that impairement?

i wonder if it is possible to replace an external js-file with an unobfuscated nice-looking (maybe altered one) and have this one executed instead. any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `unobfuscated`? Only formatting? Because it won't be easy to restore good variable/method names.

Comment: mostly meaningful indentation. i guess in some cases proper unobfuscation might be hard to accomplish but lets restrict to positive cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way. i am not accepting my answer as **the answer** b/c its not as comfortable as i would like it to be. so i am interested in further ideas.

you install foxyproxy and configure a new proxy for '*filename.js' (mind the asterisk!). as you host you use a local server, so '192.168.?.?' or 'localhost'.

thing is if the URL of the js-file to be replaced is 'http://www.abc.net/dir1/dir2/filename.js' then you have to make your new js-file accessible at 'http://[host]/dir1/dir2/filename.js'.

that setup is somewhat complicated. it should be possible to have the js-file replaced by another file anywhere on your disk. but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Take some tool which has `reformat code` option. JetBrains WebStorm for example. It should break the lines so they will be suitable for setting breakpoints.

This should take 5-10 minutes. I doubt you will be able to do anything more without spending much time.

Comment: im not sure if you got my question. its not about how to make the code readable but about how to have this readable code executed in place of the original one.

Comment: @Raffael, yes, didn't got it. How this file is referenced. It is not clear what's the problem with replacing file. Is this file located somewhere in internet?

Comment: the file is referenced in a script tag. so technically it should be possible to replace the loaded file or to reference another scriptfile before it is loaded and executed by the browser. i wonder what would be the easiest way to accomplish that.